# Unexpected behavior with multiprocessing pool imap_unordered method

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I have a process that I'm trying to parallelize with the `multiprocessing` library. Each process does a few things, but one of the things each process does is to call a function that runs an optimization. Now, 90% of the time each optimization will complete in less than 1 minute, but if it doesn't, it might never converge. There is an internal mechanism that terminates the optimization function if it doesn't converge after say, 20,000 iterations, but that can take a long time (~1hr).

Right now my code looks something like this:

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
imap_it = pool.imap_unordered(synth_worker, arg_tuples)

while 1:
    try:
        result = imap_it.next(timeout=120)
        process_result(result)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    except multiprocessing.TimeoutError:
        pass

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

This seems to work fairly well as I am able to process the first 90% of results fairly quickly, but towards the end, the longer processes start to bog things down and only 1 process completes every ~10 minutes. The weird thing is that once it gets to this point and I run `top` at the terminal, it seems like only 5-6  parallel processes are running even though I have 24 CPUs in my Pool. I see all 24 CPU's engaged at the beginning of the run, also. Meanwhile I see that there are still over 100 remaining tasks that haven't finished (or even started). I'm not utilizing any of the built-in chunking options of `imap_unordered` so my understanding is that as soon as one process finishes, the worker that was running that finished process should pick up a new one. Why would there be fewer parallel processes running than there are remaining tasks unless all remaining jobs were already allocated to the 5-6 jammed workers that are waiting for their non-convergent optimizations to hit their 20,000 iteration cutoff? Any ideas? Should I try another method to iterate over the results of my Pool as they come in?

Output of `top` at the beginning of a run [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4COJ.png)

and output of `top` once the jobs seem to get stuck [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rODss.png)

and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxnWS.png) is what stdout looks like when the jobs start to get stuck.

Comment: "Meanwhile I see that there are still over 100 remaining processes that haven't finished (or even started)." How do you observe the 100 remaining tasks? Or is it really processes? It's important to not mix the wording because your pool will only start as much processes as much cores you have. The scheduled unit the worker-processes are fed with is a task (or a batch of tasks for chunksize > 1).

Comment: My mistake. I did mean over 100 remaining tasks. I am able to observe the remaining tasks because within the `try` statement in the while loop I have a counter that counts completed tasks which I then print at the end of each iteration of the while loop.

Comment: "There is an internal mechanism that terminates the optimization function..."  How is this done? Process killing?

Comment: The optimization function also has an internal counter, so once it reaches 20,000 iterations for example, and still hasn't converged, it simply returns with the results as is and logs a warning.

Comment: Do all tasks finish (one way or the other) eventually? You could try with `Pool(maxtasksperchild=1)` and see if this changes anything. It will start a fresh process for every task.

Comment: That's actually what I was thinking I would try next. All tasks do eventually complete, but on fewer and fewer threads, which is the part that is mysterious to me. Even if I don't specify `maxtasksperchild`, my understanding was that the Pool would still assign a task to a worker one at a time, especially if I'm not using chunking.

Comment: Does CPU-utilization in total also drop , meaning you have cores idling? Insert `logger = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr(logging.DEBUG)` below `if __name__ == '__main__':` and watch out for errors.

Comment: OK I re-ran with your debugger set as well as `maxtasksperchild=1` and neither seemed to have any effect. Every single process logged the following messages:

```[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-980] worker exiting after 1 tasks
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-980] process shutting down
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-980] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-980] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-980] process exiting with exitcode 0``` with no other errors until suddenly it simply stops spawning workers with nearly 200 tasks remaining.

Comment: ...and freezes or what kind of exception do you get? Sounds like an OS thingy then. Which OS? Are you exhausting RAM?

Comment: That's the weird thing...no exceptions are generated. This is on Ubuntu 18.04. I have no reason to believe that I'm exhausting RAM.

Comment: @Darkonaut I added some links in my original post to images that show what `top` and stdout look like at the beginning of a run vs once things start to get jammed up.

Comment: I see 19 users, is this server yours?

Comment: Yes, but I am a Ph.D. student and share this server with others in my lab though I am effectively sysadmin.

Comment: Ask the sysadmin in you if he implemented some resource limits (maybe default?) like on cpu-time for example. Terminal output of `ulimit -a` could be interesting. That's really my last idea, that you are hitting some OS-resource limit with such a heavy computation.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't look like it: ```core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 386408
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 386408
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

Comment: Strange. Maybe try to reproduce this on a private machine to exclude this is a server-related issue.

Comment: I'll give that a go. Thanks for you help.